# I would like to make objects appear and disappear in the viewer with some degree of transparency

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, revit

I'm working on a revi model to put in the forge where you can read the history of the building. from the nascia - collapses - demolitions - reconstructions.
between one passage and the next I would like to add a degree of transparency (fade in fade out) for the change of models or model parts.

this is my function:

```
 function T00()
  {
  NOP_VIEWER.model.search('00', function onSuccess(dbids) {NOP_VIEWER.showAll(); 
   NOP_VIEWER.isolate(dbids); }, function onError(err) { console.error(err); }, 
  'Timeline_Storico');}.fadeToggle(400)
```

I isolate the parts of the model that I want to see.
how can i add the degree of transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest check the other post for some backgrounds on rendering machanism:
[How to set opacity of each nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974100/how-to-set-opacity-of-each-nodes)

The default materials are defined at

```
viewer.impl.matman()._materials;
```

Different fragments might share with the same material.

In the blog below, I demoed how to make the model grey out, by changing the material parameters.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/showhide-textures-object-forge-viewer
Similarly, you can set their opacity to different values. e.g.

```
 //iterate materials 
for (index in mats) {

    //index is the material name (unique string in the list)
    m = mats[index];

    //store texture info
    oldTextures[index] = m.map;
    oldColors[index] = m.color;

    //set the material without texture and the grey color
    //var grey = new THREE.Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5); 
    //m.map = null;
    //m.color = grey;

    //change transparency
    m.opacity = 0.1*index;
    m.transparent = true;
    //force update
    material.needsUpdate = true

    //mark the material dirty. The viewer will refresh
    m.needsUpdate = true; 
} 
//refresh the scene
viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, false);
```

However the problem is: since the fragments share with the material, all other fragments (with same material)will be also updated, instead of by transparency objects.

While, it can be workaround by cloning the material of specific object, changing its opacity, and finally applying this material to the object only. Of course, because it is cloned material, you need to add it to the materials list of viewer.impl.matman(). The other post demos with the codes
[How to set independent material for specific dbId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225152/how-to-set-independent-material-for-specific-dbid)
copying here for your convenience:

```
let material = fragList.getMaterial(fragId).clone();
 if (material) {
material.opacity = opacity
material.transparent = true
material.needsUpdate = true
}
    viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial ('myCustomMaterial', material, 
 true);
    viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, material);
    viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```